# broadFileSystemAccess UWP

Tags: uwp, windows-runtime, microsoft-metro, uwp-xaml

I'm trying to use `broadFileSystemAccess` Capability for UWP apps, But `broadFileSystemAccess` capability is not listed in my list of capabilites in Package.appxmanifest.

My min and max target version is 1803, build 17134, Please help me with this.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This capability is not listed in the "designer" of **Package.appxmanifest**, you have to add it manually via code.

Go to **Solution Explorer** and right-click **Package.appxmanifest**. Select **View Code**.

In the code view update the `Package` element to contain the following:

```
<Package
  ...
  xmlns:rescap="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities"
  IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp rescap">
```

Do not duplicate the `IgnorableNamespaces` attribute, just append `rescap` to the end of its value. Now scroll down below and find `<Capabilities>`. Inside add the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability as follows:

```
<rescap:Capability Name="broadFileSystemAccess" />
```

Comment: is there any API that can provide us search across the filesystem for the given file name.

Comment: Sorry for not noticing your problem. You can use StorageFilder.CreateFileQueryWithOptions with an instance of QueryOptions to search. There is a lot of properties which you can configure. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefolder.createfilequerywithoptions

Comment: I tried to do this in a xamarin forms application and then access my documents and I get System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path. my  min and target version are  
    <TargetPlatformVersion>10.0.17763.0</TargetPlatformVersion>
    <TargetPlatformMinVersion>10.0.16299.0</TargetPlatformMinVersion>

Comment: How are you trying to access the files? You must actually use StorageFile APIs, not just classic System.IO API

Comment: This answer does not appear to work as-written. I've followed the steps in the answer exactly but cannot use, `await Windows.Storage.StorageFolder.GetFolderFromPathAsync("C:\\Users\\user name")` without `E_ACCESSDENIED` getting thrown.

Comment: I really can't understand why these stupid exceptions exist. Why on earth some capabilities are present in the GUI and some other must be added, by hand, through the code? Damn.

Comment: This answer really a big live safer, since I'm newbie in UWP world I never know this exist. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way I could enable just for development and automatically have it disabled for release build?

Comment: @Nick not automatically per se, you would have to adjust the `Package.appxmanifest` file - either using two different manifests (one for development, one for release), or updating removing the capability before build (which is doable for example as part of a build pipeline)

Comment: I had to add also the runFullTrust capability besides the broadFileSystemAccess to get full File Access