# Is it possible to access ProgramData folder from UWP without file picker?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, uwp, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Can anyone share your ideas of accessing the custom paths like program data folder in the C drive from UWP application??

I am getting an access denied while accessing this path. Any special capabilities that I have to add to the AppManifest.

Basically I need to access this folder from the a KIOSK where.i have a specific file which is to be reused for KIOSK mode in UWP.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your only hope is [broadFileSystemAccess](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/files/file-access-permissions#accessing-additional-locations). Also, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559764/broadfilesystemaccess-uwp) could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to carry data of a smaller amount, you can use the System Environment Variable. You can set and get the value added in the Environmental variable from KIOSK mode.