# Check whether file has read only flag in UWP

Tags: file, uwp, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, windows-10-desktop

I am working on an UWP text editor. I have added desktop extension to it to modify system files and other read only files. The problem I have is there is no reliable way to detect if a file has read-only attribute. `FileInfo.IsReadOnly` doesn't work and `StorageFile.Attributes` has `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` when file is dragged and dropped from file explorer.

How do I reliably check whether the file has read only flag or not?

[image: File with Read-only attribute]

Comment: You mentioned `FileInfo.IsReadOnly` does not work, does it throw an error? What if your call the API from the desktop extension instead?

Comment: Callining `FileInfo.IsReadOnly` throws error in uwp app. Yes I can call the desktop extension for this. But this slows down the whole process of saving file.

Comment: Just to understand, what is the scenario where `StorageFile.Attributes` does not correctly report `ReadOnly`?

Comment: If file was drag and dropped from file-explorer, then `StorageFile.Attributes` reports `ReadOnly` even if the file itself doesn't have Read-only checked.

Comment: I have added an answer to detect readonly attribute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While there is no way to detect the readonly attribute by using dotnet methods, however [`GetFileAttributesExFromApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846626(v=vs.85)) can be used to get a lot of attributes(readonly, hidden etc.) of the file that aren't available via `StorageFile` api. Also, [`SetFileAttributesFromApp`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/mt846630(v=vs.85)) can be used to change/remove these attributes.

#### Edit

After some research and deep dive in MSDN, I came to know about `RetrievePropertiesAsync(IEnumerable<String>)` and
`SavePropertiesAsync(IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<String,Object>>)` methods for `Windows.Storage.FileProperties.StorageItemContentProperties` which can be used to get and set properties by name ([Full list of properties names](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/core-bumper)), the name [`System.FileAttributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/properties/props-system-fileattributes) can be used to get file attributes and can be used to detect if read-only flag is present. While retrieving properties always works modifying properties will only work if app has write access to file ([`Windows.Storage.StorageFile.Attributes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.fileattributes?view=winrt-19041) doesn't contain `ReadOnly` flag), although `SetFileAttributesFromApp` works for that scenario but limitation of `SetFileAttributesFromApp` is it won't work for sensitive file types (.bat, .cmd etc.). So both those methods could be used combined to have maximum effect.

Comment: @A.Caillet I can confirm this works. If you want an example check [this](https://github.com/JasonStein/Notepads/pull/636) PR in which I implemented checking read-only flag and changing read-only flag in UWP app [Notepads](https://github.com/JasonStein/Notepads). If you specifically want to know how you call these funcions check [this](https://github.com/JasonStein/Notepads/pull/636/files#diff-949c1c37e9cf816cfb2d43ad54e6e401) file.

Answer (score -1):

You can see the `Attributes` property has `ReadOnly` or not.

```
    var filePicker = new Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker();
    filePicker.ViewMode = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail;
    filePicker.SuggestedStartLocation = Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.VideosLibrary;
    foreach (string format in HelperUP.subtitlesFormat)
        filePicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(format);
    var file = await filePicker.PickSingleFileAsync();
    if (file == null)
        return;

    Debug.WriteLine(file.Attributes);
```

[image: F]

Comment: I have mentioned in my question that my app supports drag and drop functionality and for files that are drag and dropped `StorageFile.Attributes` returns `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` too.

Comment: For the files you drag-drop, it's always read-only. This is by design.

Comment: See this issue, https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2421

Comment: I have seen the issue you linked and I know the drag and drop files are read-only (and I know workaround to bypass that in uwp using `Windows.Storage.PathIO`). My question is to detect whether the Read-only flag is enabled in file properties.

Comment: I have added an answer to detect readonly attribute.

Answer (score -1):

The reason `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` throws an exception is that the `System.IO` APIs don't have access to arbitrary file locations on the hard drive in UWP.

On the other hand, a `StorageFile` opened in the app via drag & drop has this attribute set too, which is a problem that is [continuously being discussed](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml/issues/2421) and hopefully will be fixed in a future version.

The only workaround I can think of (apart from always using the desktop extension) is declaring the `broadFileSystemAccess` capability (I have described the process [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50559764/broadfilesystemaccess-uwp) for example). This is a capability which gives you access to the whole filesystem and allows you to get a file using an arbitrary path with the `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync` method (see [Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.storagefile.getfilefrompathasync?view=winrt-19041)). Please note you will need to explain why this capability is required when you submit the application to the Microsoft Store.

With broad filesystem access, you could take the drag & drop `StorageFile`, take its `Path` and retrieve the same file again using `StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync`. This new copy of the file will no longer have the "false-positive" Read Only attribute and will reflect the actual attribute state from the filesystem.

Comment: So there is no way in uwp to detect if readonly flag is enabled for a file?? Also you don't need `broadFileSystemAccess` to write to file that has been dragged-dropped from explorer (seems overkill and unreliable to me). I have posted a way [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62638922/write-to-file-in-uwp-that-has-been-drag-dropped-from-explorer/62638923#62638923) using a workaround with `PathIO` api.