# Write to file in uwp that has been drag-dropped from explorer

Tags: file-io, uwp, windows-10-universal, file-writing, uwp-c#

If file is dragged and dropped from file explorer it has `FileAttributes.ReadOnly` flag for `StorageFile.Attributes` parameter. In that case using `StorageFile` api to write to file will give error. How to write to file in this case??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case `PathIO` api can be used to write to file (unless file is a system file). Convert data to write into bytes array and then add following code to write to file:

```
await PathIO.WriteBytesAsync(file.Path, bytes);
```

This will write to these files without any error. You don't need any additional permission like `broadFileSystemAccess` for this.